# What is the simplest formula for smooth step function (Or smooth transition function)?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, smooth-functions

I am working on designing a smooth step function, which is changing from 0 to 1 while x changes from a to b, and this f(x) are expected can equal to 0 or 1 exactly at point a or at point b. I am using the sigmoid function which only the position of f(x)=1/2 be controlled not the point a and b (see the following picture).
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQl6M.png)
Thank you very much.

Comment: Let $f(t)$ be the sigmoid function. Have you tried functions of the form $f(at+b)$ where $a$ and $b$ are the constants you can pick to satisfy your requirements?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes, I have tried it. However, the changing points from 0 to 1 and from 1 to 0, cannot be exactly controlled. And the sigmoid function cannot meet that the f(t) equals to exactly 0 or 1. Do you have some solutions on it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Surely *these are additional conditions* that are missing from your question. Can you please edit your post to add all those additional constraints, so that people who try to answer won't go down the same rabbit hole as I did ...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have revised the question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a cubic polynomial?  That should provide you with enough degrees of freedom (4) to control the location of where the value is 0 or 1 and the slope at those endpoints.  Of course outside of those endpoint the cubit wouldn't make sense and you may need a different piecewise solution.

[Smoothstep](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Smoothstep&oldid=1058671745) is an example of this type of function.

You may also be interested in: [Continuous non-piecewise equivalent of smoothstep function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/188274/continuous-non-piecewise-equivalent-of-smoothstep-function)